# oh-my-fish unable to install plugins

Tags: shell

I'm having a problme to install plugin after playing omf for a while.

```
> omf install default
Installing theme default
ssh: Could not resolve hostname \033[38;5;15mhttps: No address associated with hostname
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Could not install theme default.
```

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall oh-my-fish, and even the fish as well, the still can't get arround the problem.

Any one have idea on how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have been already discussed on Oh My Fish Github. For anyone still having this issue, please check [issue 229](https://github.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/issues/229).

**TL;DR:** The issue is caused by a function wrapping `cat` command, which is polluting output with malformed escape sequences.